# How create a unittest that will test if method was called for specific class with specific argument?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Here is my code

```
module_a.py

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def send(self):
        print('We send some message here')
        # send self.message

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super(Child, self).__init__()


module_b.py

from module_a import Child

def some_function():
    # do something
    Child('Some Message Here').send()
    # do something
```

Is there any way to test that `.send()` was called for Child not for parent and `self.message` inside `.send()` equals to some value.

Thanks

UPD: I am asking about writing a unit test and my main problem is how to patch /mock that in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can check the Type of self (your Object)

eg:

```
    class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def send(self):
        print(type(self))
        # send self.message

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super(Child, self).__init__()



Child('Some Message Here').send()

Parent().send()
```

results in:

```
<class '__main__.Child'>
<class '__main__.Parent'>
```

if you want to Check if the calling Object is a child use isinstance which will give you a boolean. Although watch out, this only works for Child Checks, as a Child Class is also an instance of a Parent Class!

```
isinstance(self, Child)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I miss an important part of my question. I don`t need to check it in the working code. I am asking about writing a unit test and my main problem is how to patch /mock that in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking your test case using `patch`. The mocked class can be checked for the `call_count` or even by the arguments the function of the class is called with i.e. `assert_called_with`. In your case `Child.send`.

Since you are mocking the Child class, it confirms that the attribute `send` comes from it and not from the Parent class.

```
from module_b import some_function
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("module_b.Child.send")
    def test_some_func(self, mock_send):
        some_function()
        self.assertEqual(mock_send.call_count, 1)
```

In case to check for the mocked class, it can be adapted and mocked as follows:

```
from module_b import some_function
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("module_b.Child")
    def test_some_func(self, mock_child):
        some_function()
        mock_child.assert_called_with("Some Message Here")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Changes to the code of your file module_a.py

I have completed your method `send()` and I think that the modifications are in compliance with your comment (*'send self.message'*): in the method `send()` I have introduced the instruction `instanceof()`.

I show below my code for the file `module_a.py`:

```py
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def send(self):
        print(type(self))
        if isinstance(self, Child):
            # send self.message
            print("send Child: " + str(self.message))
        else:
            # for Parent doesn't exist self.message
            print("send Parent!")

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

### Test file module_b.py

In my opinion is not necessary use patch for your test. At base of this consideration is that the method `send()` is defined only in the `Parent`, so it is available for both instance of Child and Parent. But this is only my opinion..

In the same folder of `module_a.py` I write 2 tests in test file `module_b.py`:

- in the first test it is created `sut_child`, an istance of class Child, and invoked its method `send()`; after that I check the value of `self.message` and that the object `sut_child` is of type Child
- in the second test it is create `sut_parent`, an istance of class Parent, and invoked its method `send()`; after that I check that the object `sut_parent` is of type Parent

Below the code of test file `module_b.py`:

```py
from module_a import Child, Parent
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_send_func_child(self):
        sut_child = Child('Some Message Here')
        sut_child.send()
        self.assertEqual('Some Message Here', sut_child.message)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(sut_child, Child))

    def test_send_func_parent(self):
        sut_parent = Parent()
        sut_parent.send()
        self.assertFalse(isinstance(sut_parent, Child))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### Output of execution of module_b.py

If you execute `module_b.py` the output is:

```
# output of test_send_func_child:
<class 'module_a.Child'>
send Child: Some Message Here

# output of test_send_func_parent
<class 'module_a.Parent'>
send Parent!

# output for the execution of 2 tests (the assert are correct)
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```